# Getting one previous record by date from each current one

Tags: mysql

Am trying to get the previous fuelling millage when the vehicle was fuelling at that specific date.

My table structure looks like this:

```
id      vehicle     center      dates           odometer        quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11      UAY329R     257         2017-04-01      153329          15  
12      S022        254         2017-03-22      139828          15  
13      UAP614Z     254         2017-04-01      211410          15  
14      S022        254         2017-03-25      139928          15  
15      UAY848Q     254         2017-04-01      239813          15  
16      C052        257         2017-04-11      15016           12.06   
17      UAP258A     254         2017-03-29      29495           20  
18      S022        254         2017-04-12      140078          35.66   
19      UAP258A     254         2017-04-01      29575           20  
20      UDL146E     254         2017-04-01      223701          20  
21      UAP258A     254         2017-04-03      29675           20  
22      UDL146E     254         2017-04-04      223851          5
```

am trying to get an output like this:

```
prev_id     PrevOdo     CurrentId   CurrentOdo      Distance    Vehicle     Dates
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8           139708          12      139828          120         S022        2017-03-22
12          139828          14      139928          100         S022        2017-03-25
12          139928          18      140078          150         S022        2017-04-12
10          29415           17      29495           80          UAP258A     2017-03-29
17          29495           19      29575           80          UAP258A     2017-04-01
19          29575           21      29675           100         UAP258A     2017-04-03
7           223601          20      223701          100         UDL146E     2017-04-01
20          223701          22      223851          150         UDL146E     2017-04-04
```

My query is partly working but if there are more than one record in previous transactions, the second one shows incorrect PrevOdo.

My query is as show below, Please help me and thank you in advance.

```
SELECT prev_id,  p.odometer AS 'PrevOdo', t.id AS 'CurrentId', t.odometer AS 'CurrentOdo', (t.odometer - p.odometer) AS 'Distance', t.vehicle AS 'Vehicle', t.dates AS 'Dates'
  FROM ( SELECT t.id, t.odometer, t.vehicle, t.dates, t.quantity, (
                    SELECT id
                      FROM ISSUANCE
                     WHERE dates < t.dates AND vehicle = t.vehicle
                     ORDER BY id DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                  ) prev_id
 FROM ISSUANCE t
 WHERE t.dates BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-15')
 t LEFT JOIN ISSUANCE p ON t.prev_id = p.id
 ORDER BY t.vehicle
```

the query is filtered by date.

This is the table structure ive used coz some records are mixed up so i cant follow by id, am using date. Thanks in advance.

```
drop table if exists issuance;

create table issuance (
    id int,
    vehicle varchar(20),
    center int,
    dates date,
    odometer int,
    quantity int
);

insert into issuance values
 (02, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-14', 140178, 5),
 (04, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-18', 140378, 5),
 (11, 'UAY329R', 257, '2017-04-01', 153329, 15),
 (12, 'S022', 254, '2017-03-22', 139828, 15),
 (13, 'UAP614Z', 254, '2017-04-01', 211410, 15),
 (14, 'S022', 254, '2017-03-25', 139928, 15),
 (15, 'UAY848Q', 254, '2017-04-01', 239813, 15),
 (16, 'C052', 257, '2017-04-11', 15016 , 12.06),   
 (17, 'UAP258A', 254, '2017-03-29', 29495 , 20),
 (18, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-12', 140078, 35.66),   
 (19, 'UAP258A', 254, '2017-04-01', 29575 , 20),
 (20, 'UDL146E', 254, '2017-04-01', 223701, 20),
 (21, 'UAP258A', 254, '2017-04-03', 29675 , 20),
 (22, 'UDL146E', 254, '2017-04-04', 223851, 5),
 (23, 'S022', 254, '2017-03-26', 139948, 5),
 (25, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-16', 140278, 5),
 (27, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-19', 140478, 5),
 (98, 'S022', 254, '2017-04-22', 140578, 5);

select  prev.id as PrevId,
    prev.odometer as PrevOdo,
    cur.id as CurId,
    cur.odometer as CurOdo,
    cur.odometer - prev.odometer as distance,
    cur.vehicle as Vehicle,
    cur.dates as  Dates
 from    issuance cur
 join    (
        select  t1.id, max(t2.id) as prev_id
        from    issuance t1
        join    issuance t2
        on      t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and
                t1.dates > t2.dates
        group by t1.id
    ) mid
 on      cur.id = mid.id
 join    issuance prev
 on      prev.id = mid.prev_id
 where   cur.dates between '2017-03-01' and '2017-05-15'
 ORDER BY Vehicle ASC, Dates ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build a query for that in two steps: first I'd get the `id / prev_id` couples

```
select  t1.id, max(t2.id) as prev_id
from    issuance t1
join    issuance t2
on      t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and
        t1.id > t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Now I would use that as an intermediate join in the self join of the original table:

```
select  prev.id as PrevId,
        prev.odometer as PrevOdo,
        cur.id as CurId,
        cur.odometer as CurOdo,
        cur.odometer - prev.odometer as distance,
        cur.vehicle as Vehicle,
        cur.dates as  Dates
from    issuance cur
join    (
            select  t1.id, max(t2.id) as prev_id
            from    issuance t1
            join    issuance t2
            on      t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and
                    t1.id > t2.id
            group by t1.id
        ) mid
on      cur.id = mid.id
join    issuance prev
on      prev.id = mid.prev_id
where   cur.dates between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-15';
```

**Edit**

Since you cannot rely on IDs ordering to be consistent with dates ordering, you will have to change the joining criteria; first of all, you will need the latest date from the inner query instead of the maximum id:

```
select  t1.id, max(t2.dates) as prev_dates
from    issuance t1
join    issuance t2
on      t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and
        t1.dates > t2.dates
group by t1.id
```

Then this table will have to be joined differenty

```
select  prev.id as PrevId,
        prev.odometer as PrevOdo,
        cur.id as CurId,
        cur.odometer as CurOdo,
        cur.odometer - prev.odometer as distance,
        cur.vehicle as Vehicle,
        cur.dates as  Dates
from    issuance cur
join    (
            select  t1.id, max(t2.dates) as prev_dates
            from    issuance t1
            join    issuance t2
            on      t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and
                    t1.dates > t2.dates
            group by t1.id
        ) mid
on      cur.id = mid.id
join    issuance prev
on      prev.dates = mid.prev_dates and
        prev.vehicle = cur.vehicle /* the mid calculated field is not sufficient anymore */
where   cur.dates between '2017-03-01' and '2017-05-15'
order by cur.vehicle asc, cur.dates asc
```

Working rextester [here](http://rextester.com/DGGXG80447)

Comment: Hi @Stefano, i have the done `on  t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and t1. dates > t2. dates ` so that it can be accurate on the exact previous date of refueling and i still have the same issue.


`8941 21560 9448 22455 895 C006 2017-04-01
9448 22455 9447 22600 145 C006 2017-04-05
9448 22455 9446 22920 465 C006 2017-04-07`

Comment: the id 22455 is repeating twice and in the last record the id should be 22600

Comment: I set up a working example [here](http://rextester.com/LYPSO63895) with the sample data you provided, and no duplicates are showing up... can you edit your question with the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Hi @Stefano, it works well. thanks so much. for some reason i dont know where the loop stops, instead of 23153 as previous ID, its showing 22903, check out this link of the results i have found. am using sequel pro. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1l1i4vs3ek1enj/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-18%20at%2012.23.55%20PM.png?dl=0), might you know why am getting this?

Comment: There's no way I can understand what's causing your problem from that screenshot. Please create a verifiable example on rextester or at least edit your question with sample data that cause the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Stefano. i have the sample data that is somehow confusing me at the bottom of the question, i am filtering by date.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)